# Yii2- How to pass model id via redirect

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hi I want to pass the model id in redirect using `url`. But when I try to pass it I am getting the error

**Error**

> Object not found!
>   The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404

This error generates when I try to do this

```
$this->redirect(Url::to('/process?file_name=' . $file_name . "&header_no=" . $_POST['header_no'],['id'=>$model->id]));
```

**URL :** `http://localhost:225/process?file_name=excel_12.xlsx&header_no=1` the Url is wrong the right one should be like this `http://localhost:225/inventory-web/backend/web/....../...`

**Error2:**

> Not Found (#404)
>   Page not found.
>   The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

**URL:**`http://localhost:225/inventory-web/backend/web/process?file_name=excel_12.xlsx&header_no=1?id=1`

How I can pass the model id?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried like this and it works perfectly fine for me.

```
$this->redirect('/didmaster/didtenant?id=' . $model['em_id']);
```

Try this,

```
 $this->redirect('/process?file_name=' . $file_name . "&header_no=" . $_POST['header_no'] . "&id=" . $model->id);
```

or

```
 $this->redirect(array(
        'process',
        'file_name' => $file_name,
        'header_no' => $_POST['header_no'],
        'id' => $model->id
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirection from response also:

```
 Yii::$app->response->redirect(['/process', 'file_name'=> $file_name,
            'header_no'=> $_POST['header_no'] ,
            'id'=>$model->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as in yii2 ref 
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#redirect()-detail

you can use

> an array in the format of [$route, ...name-value pairs...] (e.g.
>   ['site/index', 'ref' => 1])  yii\helpers\Url::to() will be used to
>   convert the array into a URL

```
$this->redirect(['/process', 'file_name'=> $file_name, 
                             'header_no'=> $_POST['header_no'] ,
                             'id'=>$model->id]);
```